# How to retrieve an image from Firestore database - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i was wondering how to retrieve an image from Firestore, i was trying and reading and watching tutorials so i have come with this solution:

1- Upload images to Firebase storage.

2- Go to Firestore create a collection and a document with field name and value of image path. ( collection "majorChallenges", doc "challenge-1", field "source", value "image path url")

3- Initiate a Firestore Instance:  `var _fireStoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;`

4- Access the Database collection using QuerySnapshot: `QuerySnapshot qn = await _fireStoreInstance.collection("majorChallenges").get();`

5- now after that am not sure how to setState, initState, return and display the image inside Scaffold or Container.

some tutorials are using the image link or name which is not efficient for me what if i have to change the image in the future so the best solution i believe must not use the image name it should access the collection and the doc and retrieve the image path.

i already set up the read and write permissions and i have accessed the database before to retrieve text so no authorisation problems, I would be very thankful if someone could complete the steps for us

Answer (score 0):

I can now answer my own question, first of all it is wrong to specify this operation in steps because there are a lot of approaches to achieve this goal, and the approach i am using is pretty nice and simple using QuerySnapshot. so to retrieve picture we need simply do these steps (for my approach):

1- we need to declare a string variable then create asynchronous method that will fetch the image URL from Firestore and update the variable state using set state method, inside this method we can initiate a Firestore instance and a QuerySnapshot:

```
String img = "";

  fetchMajorChallengeImage() async {
    var _fireStoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn =
        await _fireStoreInstance.collection("majorChallenges").get();

    setState(() {
      img = qn.docs[0]["source"];
    });

    return qn.docs;
  }
```

2- we will initiate the state using initState method and call our function inside:

```
void initState() {
    fetchMajorChallengeImage();
    super.initState();
  }
```

3- now the image is retrieved and the path stored to "img" variable we declared, so we need to display the image, here its your choice where and how to display the image but for me this is how i displayed it:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Image.network(img, height: 150, fit: BoxFit.fill),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

note that it must be displayed inside Image.network() widget because the variable holds a URL value fetched from the firestore collection > doc > value and now the image is retrieved and displayed successfully.